# Parameters of open(POST) ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem with this parameters when I call them in php file
show this error : Undefined index: qu , class , sub

```
function sender(qu , sub)
{
    var classs = getCheckedRadioValue('classs');`enter code here`
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            return true;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST" , "controller/add_qu.php?qu="+qu+"&class="+classs+"&sub="+sub , true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Is it 'classs' or 'class' ??

Comment: can you remove the sapce after 'qu' making it  sender( qu, sub ).

Comment: not work..i test 'qu','class','sub' by alert() it's work but when i call them in php file show the error

Comment: can you try it with 'GET' instead of 'POST' ?

Comment: I am sorry for that but not work :(

Comment: Would you show us the code for 'add_qu.php"?

Comment: `if($_REQUEST)
{      $post['question'] = $_REQUEST['qu'];
        $post['class']    = $_REQUEST['class'];
        $post['subject']  = $_REQUEST['sub'];

     include 'models/database.php';
  $tablename = "questions";
  $db = new database("localhost" , "posts" , "root" , "");
        $add = $db->add($tablename , $post);
        if ($add) {
         include 'controller/posts_view.php';
        }else{echo "non";}
    
}`